# Qt for Android - Statusbar color

Tags: android, c++, qt, user-interface, statusbar

Does anyone know a way to change the Android statusbar color of a Qt Application?

So far i've tried a lot of c++ solutions - all of them seem to fail, because that code does not run inside the main ui thread - and some xml adjustments in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `styles.xml` - that seems to influence at least the toolbar* but not the statusbar*..

Can someone maybe offer a c++ solution, or has anyone reached results with xml?

Thanks for your help!

---

*about the terms 'statusbar' and 'toolbar': Android calls two different ui elements 'statusbar'. So in this case, i'm calling one of them 'toolbar'. To clarify:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Thanks to [Volodymyr Shevchyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2784899/volodymyr-shevchyk)

**Solution:**

```cpp
QtAndroid::runOnAndroidThread([=]()
{
    QAndroidJniObject window = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("getWindow", "()Landroid/view/Window;");
    window.callMethod<void>("addFlags", "(I)V", 0x80000000);          // FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
    window.callMethod<void>("clearFlags", "(I)V", 0x04000000);        // FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS
    window.callMethod<void>("setStatusBarColor", "(I)V", 0xffffffff); // Desired statusbar color
});                                                      // A R G B
```

using extracts frome [here](https://github.com/jpnurmi/statusbar/blob/master/src/statusbar.cpp) and [here](https://www.kdab.com/qt-android-run-c-code-android-ui-thread/).

Make sure, that you are on Qt version 5.7 or above. Otherwise `QtAndroid::runOnAndroidThread` won't work.

EDIT: Starting from Qt >= 6.2, this code needs to be run on the UI thread (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnativeinterface-qandroidapplication.html#runOnAndroidMainThread)).

> **Note** If you're using white, or some other very bright color as background, the statusbar text can be made a little darker using the following code:
>
> ```cpp
> QAndroidJniObject decorView = window.callObjectMethod("getDecorView", "()Landroid/view/View;");
> decorView.callMethod<void>("setSystemUiVisibility", "(I)V", 0x00002000);
> ```